# enum in ordered list or set

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I want to create an ordered set, or list, and add enums to the collection so they are  inserted in enum order.
Can I do this without creating an explicit comparator?  Is there a collection that will use the inherent order of the enum to maintain the order in the collection?

Example in Groovy of what I want to do (I expect it will be similar for Java with a for loop instead of a closure):

```
TreeSet<TransactionElement> elements = new TreeSet<TransactionElement>() 
        elementList.each{ element -> elements.add(element)}
```

TransactionElement is an enum and the elements should be added to the TreeSet in the order they are listed in the enum

UPDATE:
Solution I went with:

```
EnumSet<TransactionElement> elements = EnumSet.noneOf(TransactionElement.class); 
        elementList.each{ element -> elements.add(element)}
```

Some great examples of how to use EnumSet and EnumMap [here](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/07/sleek-enummap-and-enumset.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a `Set` of `enum` values, then [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is probably your best bet. Not only is it more efficient that using a non-specialized `Set`, it also guarantees that the iteration will work in the natural order of the `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could tale a look at the [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

By default Enums declaration order defines the natural ordering of the Enums. From javadoc of compareTo:

> Enum constants are only comparable to
>   other enum constants of the same enum
>   type. The natural order implemented by
>   this method is the order in which the
>   constants are declared.